# How can I access some properties in userControl from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, singleton

My program is consists of a `userControl` and a `class` in *C# winform* environment. when I click on a `button` in `userControl`, an instance of my `class` is created and the main process starts. I want to interact with my `class` with `userControl` through the program is running. for example, I want to show some massages from `class` to a `textBox` property in the designed `userControl`. I can not instantiate from my `userControl` in my `class` because it is wrong and can not access running `userControl` properties. So, How can I do it? Is it a good solution to set `userControl` a **singleton** class? Do u recommend a better solution?

**Edit:** **For more clarification:**
I want to call a method from the `class` and pass an argument (*string*) into it. Then `textBox` in the `userControl` should show the passed argument! This procedure would be repeated whenever it has an output in the `class`!

**Update:** here is code sample:
In the class definition:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        //do sth
        if (a condition)
        {
            //It is wrong to create an instance but I want to explain my purpose. It is what I need!
            searchPanel sp = new searchPanel();
            sp.showMessage("...");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is userControl:

```
public partial class searchPanel : UserControl
{
    public searchPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void showMessage(string message)
    {
        textBox.AppendText(message);
        textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, How can I do it?

You could do this by implementing [events](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_events.htm). This way you can signal every class that is *subscribing* to your "`class`" events when whatever you want happens. Imagine your "`class`" just completes to sum up 10 integer numbers; you *fire* a event informing this operation just happened. Your "`userControl`" class is *subscribing* to this event and will be able to execute a function to change whatever control in the form you want. By using events you keep class isolation, avoiding things like global state in your code.

> Is it a good solution to set userControl a singleton class?

No, you should avoid using singleton as a pattern in your code. Above all using singleton as global state to expose your "`class`" to "`userControl`" is probably evidence of [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Comment: thank you for the second answer. but please consider new edit in the question. I want to handle the userControl from another class. For example, I want to pass string values into textBox whenever the main process in the class wants to show a message to the user.

Comment: @CommunityAns my answer doesn't change even after your question update. You can use `events` to do what you want.

Comment: Can I manually call events from the class? An event is enabled by action but there is no action in my source code. I want to show messages like: "Your file is reading..", "new file is created", and etc. You can explain your meaning by **code sample**.

Comment: @CommunityAns this is exactly why I suggested you to use `events` buddy. Please take a read on the texts I linked in my answer to fully understand what I meant.

Comment: You can fire an `event` when your custom class is reading a file and by subscribing to this `event`, the classe `userControl` will be able to change the textbox or whatever other control you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using the WPF Command Pattern and binding ([Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview)). This is the recommended approach.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <SearchPanel />
</Window>
```

**SearchPanel.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>

    <Button Command="{Binding ShowMessageCommand}" />

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
  <StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**SearchPanel.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SearchPanel : UserControl
{
  public SearchPanel()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  } 
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string message;
  public string Message
  {
    get => this.message;
    set
    {
      this.message = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  ICommand ShowMessageCommand => new RelayCommand(CreateMessage);


  // Command callback
  private void CreateMessage()
  {
    this.Message = "This is a message for display in the UI";
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

The helper class to create a reusable command:

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// An implementation independent ICommand implementation.
/// Enables instant creation of an ICommand without implementing the ICommand interface for each command.
/// The individual Execute() an CanExecute() members are supplied via delegates.
/// <seealso cref="System.Windows.Input.ICommand"/>
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The type of <c>RelayCommand</c> actually is a <see cref="System.Windows.Input.ICommand"/></remarks>
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
  protected readonly Func<Task> executeAsyncNoParam;
  protected readonly Action executeNoParam;
  protected readonly Func<bool> canExecuteNoParam;
  private readonly Func<object, Task> executeAsync;
  private readonly Action<object> execute;
  private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;
  /// <summary>
  /// Raised when RaiseCanExecuteChanged is called.
  /// </summary>
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
      : this(execute, (param) => true)
  {
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="executeNoParam">The execution logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Action executeNoParam)
      : this(executeNoParam, () => true)
  {
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="executeAsync">The awaitable execution logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Func<object, Task> executeAsync)
      : this(executeAsync, (param) => true)
  {
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="executeAsyncNoParam">The awaitable execution logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Func<Task> executeAsyncNoParam)
      : this(executeAsyncNoParam, () => true)
  {
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="executeNoParam">The execution logic.</param>
  /// <param name="canExecuteNoParam">The execution status logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Action executeNoParam, Func<bool> canExecuteNoParam)
  {
    this.executeNoParam = executeNoParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(executeNoParam));
    this.canExecuteNoParam = canExecuteNoParam;
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
  /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
  {
    this.execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="executeAsyncNoParam">The awaitable execution logic.</param>
  /// <param name="canExecuteNoParam">The execution status logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Func<Task> executeAsyncNoParam, Func<bool> canExecuteNoParam)
  {
    this.executeAsyncNoParam = executeAsyncNoParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(executeAsyncNoParam));
    this.canExecuteNoParam = canExecuteNoParam;
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new command.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="executeAsync">The awaitable execution logic.</param>
  /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
  public RelayCommand(Func<object, Task> executeAsync, Predicate<object> canExecute)
  {
    this.executeAsync = executeAsync ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(executeAsync));
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Determines whether this RelayCommand can execute in its current state.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.</returns>
  public bool CanExecute()
  {
    return this.canExecuteNoParam == null || this.canExecuteNoParam();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Executes the RelayCommand on the current command target.
  /// </summary>
  public async void Execute()
  {
    if (this.executeAsyncNoParam != null)
    {
      await ExecuteAsync();
      return;
    }
    this.executeNoParam();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Executes the RelayCommand on the current command target.
  /// </summary>
  public async Task ExecuteAsync()
  {
    if (this.executeAsyncNoParam != null)
    {
      await this.executeAsyncNoParam();
      return;
    }

    await Task.Run(() => this.executeNoParam());
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Determines whether this RelayCommand can execute in its current state.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="parameter">
  /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, 
  /// this object can be set to null.
  /// </param>
  /// <returns>true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.</returns>
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Executes the RelayCommand on the current command target.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="parameter">
  /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, 
  /// this object can be set to null.
  /// </param>
  public async void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    if (parameter == null)
    {
      Execute();
      return;
    }

    if (this.executeAsync != null)
    {
      await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
      return;
    }
    this.execute(parameter);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Executes the RelayCommand on the current command target.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="parameter">
  /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, 
  /// this object can be set to null.
  /// </param>
  public async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
  {
    if (this.executeAsync != null)
    {
      await this.executeAsync(parameter);
      return;
    }

    await Task.Run(() => this.execute(parameter));
  }
}
```

I recommend some reading on MVVM and Commanding e.g. [Basic MVVM and ICommand Usage Example](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/813345/basic-mvvm-and-icommand-usage-example) or [Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview)

---

Alternative approach using a simple `Button.Click` event handler:

**SearchPanel.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>

    <Button Click="ShowMessage_OnButtonClick" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="MessageTextBlock" />
  <StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**SearchPanel.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SearchPanel : UserControl
{
  public SearchPanel()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  } 

  private void ShowMessage_OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.MessageTextBlock = "This is a message for display in the UI";
  }
}
```

[Events and XAML code-behind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview-wpf#events-and-xaml-code-behind)